# Determine all functions $f(n)$ such that $\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} = \frac{1}{c}$ then $\frac{1}{f(a)} + \frac{1}{f(b)} = \frac{1}{f(c)}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, contest-math, integers

Determine all functions $f(n)$ from the positive integers to the positive integers which satisfy the following condition: whenever $a,b,$ and $c$ are positive integers such that $\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} = \frac{1}{c}$ then $\frac{1}{f(a)} + \frac{1}{f(b)} = \frac{1}{f(c)}$.

---

**Attempt**

We want to find the form of $f(n)$. Notice that if $n$ is a positive integer, then the only possible solution to 
$$ \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} = \frac{1}{n} $$
is only $a=b=2n$.

So we must only have that 
$$ f(n) = \frac{f(2n)}{2}$$

If $n=1$ then $2f(1) = f(2)$, if $n=2$ then $2f(2) = f(4)$. $n=3$ then $2f(3) = f(6)$.

$$ f(1) = f(2)/2 $$
$$  f(2) = f(4)/2 $$
$$  f(3) = f(6)/2 $$
$$  f(4) = f(8)/2 $$
$$ f(5) = f(10)/2 $$
$$ \vdots $$

From here we can easily see that $$ f(1) =  \frac{f(2)}{2} = \frac{f(4)}{2^{2}} = \frac{f(8)}{2^{3}} = ... $$

So we have $f(2) = 2f(1), f(4) = 4f(1), f(8) = 8f(1), ...$

$$ f(2^{k}) = 2^{k} f(1)...$$

then also $f(3) = f(6)/2 = f(12)/4 = f(24)/8 = …,$ which means

$$ f(3 \times 2^{k}) = 2^{k} f(3)  $$

Comment: $a=b=2n$ is not the only possible solution to $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=\frac{1}{n}$. What about, say, $\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: More generally, $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}+\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\geq1$.

Comment: @Axion004 so the answer is just $f(ab) = af(b)$?